# Translating a regex into a DOM range

Tags: javascript, regex

First off, I need to make clear, I am NOT trying the bad idea of parsing markup directly with regular expressions.

I want to find any JavaScript library which, when supplied with a DOM object, translates a supplied regular expression (used for matching TEXT ONLY) into a DOM range within that DOM object. Unlike parsing markup purely with regular expressions, this can in theory be implemented in a manner that is 100% reliable.

For example, let's say we wanted to extract all occurrences of the phrase "my old friend" out of a DOM object but without losing the internal formatting; given the following markup:

```
<div>Hello, my <i>old</i> friend.</div>
```

and the regular expression:

```
/my old friend/
```

...it would be possible for code to say use the regex to search against the `textContent` of the supplied element (the `<div>`), and then when finding the offset of the match, iterate recursively through the child text and element nodes, counting up the length of the text nodes until the count matched the index and then set this point as the beginning of the range. Then, using the length of the regex match, keep iterating through the nodes in a similar manner (tallying text node length, etc.) to find the end of the range. Then use `Range`'s `cloneContents()` (or `extractContents()` if we wish to remove the phrase from the original node too, split the node, etc.) to get our safely extracted DOM which faithfully preserves internal markup (i.e., `my <i>old</i> friend`).

Does such a JavaScript library exist?

Comment: I don't think it does the regular expression part for you (but that's really just a recursive node-walking function anyway) but [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) could help with the range stuff. Good luck,